# How does embedding the Lightning Scheduler in an external website behave?

Tags: embedded-services, lightning-scheduler

When the Lightning Scheduler is embedded in an external website not built-in Salesforce Communities or Force.com sites, will a new lead be created in the system by the Guest User every time someone schedules an appointment? Or will the appointments be created under the Guest user's contact in Salesforce?

We have an external website built on Java where a user logs in. This user is created as a Person Account record in Salesforce. Now, when the user logs in to the external website and schedules an appointment, how do we ensure that the appointment record is created under the appropriate Person Account record? Similarly, can the logged-in user modify/cancel the appointments from the external website?